# Converting International date time to local timezone time

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am scraping a website of Greece for some events and getting the event time for EEST timezone(which is their local time).
Now I have some events created in my DB and I am storing UNIX_TIMESTAMP as the datetime.

I need to convert the scraped EEST time to my local time(IST) and converted in timestamo.
Then i need to check whether the two is same. If so I will insert the scrape data.

For that I am using a function but the two timestamps are not matching in any given date. Please tell me what I am doing wrong or what should I do!

```
public function date_convert($dt, $tz1, $df1, $tz2, $df2) {
      $res = '';
      if(!in_array($tz1, timezone_identifiers_list())) { // check source timezone
        trigger_error(__FUNCTION__ . ': Invalid source timezone ' . $tz1, E_USER_ERROR);
      } elseif(!in_array($tz2, timezone_identifiers_list())) { // check destination timezone
        trigger_error(__FUNCTION__ . ': Invalid destination timezone ' . $tz2, E_USER_ERROR);
      } else {
        // create DateTime object
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($df1, $dt, new DateTimeZone($tz1));
        // check source datetime
        if($d && DateTime::getLastErrors()["warning_count"] == 0 && DateTime::getLastErrors()["error_count"] == 0) {
          // convert timezone
          $d->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($tz2));
          // convert dateformat
          $res = $d->format($df2);
        } else {
          trigger_error(__FUNCTION__ . ': Invalid source datetime ' . $dt . ', ' . $df1, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
      }

      return $res;
}
```

calling it as

```
echo $dt = self::date_convert('2014-08-05 15:30:00','Europe/Athens','Y-m-d H:i:s','Asia/Kolkata','Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br/>';
```

Stored timestamp against the same date(2014-08-05 18:00:00) in table is `1407241800`

Some iterations:

Date(Europe/Athens) ---- Return(Asia/Kolkata) ----- Timestamp ------ Stored Timestamp

2014-08-05 15:30:00 ----   2014-08-05 18:00:00 -----      1407250800 -----    1407241800

2014-05-01 12:30:00 ----   2014-05-01 15:00:00 -----      1398936600 -----    1398945600

Comment: Do us a favor and show a few iterations of the original value, expected value, and actual value you are getting so we can see better what is happening?

Comment: at last found the solution! My timezone was not set up as Asia/Kolkata..Now the timestamps match.